# Protected directory issue on web server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, cpanel

When I setup a password protected directory in cpanel for my website, if I use *www.example.com/protected* it correctly prompts for a username and password but if I use *example.com/protected* it lets me access the proctected area.

The main site .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /public/404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this please?

Many Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell this to apache by prepending the following rule before your rules to redirect a url without www to a one with www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be no difference between www and non-www.  Your issue is probably browser cache, or you logged into the non-www version and forgot.

Comment: Unfortunately not David - first thing I cleared. links are the same files ie example.com and www.example.com